# In $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$, if $a^3+b^3+c^3=0$ then $1-\omega$ divides at least one of $a,b,c$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

This is problem 3.26 (self-study) in "Ireland and Rosen"

> > If $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ and none are equal to zero, and $a^3 + b^3 +c^3 = 0$ , show at least one of $a,b,c$ is divisible by $1-\omega$. Where $\omega$ is the cube root of unity.

The prior two problems have produced the following results:

-- Any element in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$, $a+b\omega\equiv 0,1,2 \pmod {1-\omega}$.

-- For any $a\in \mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ where $a\equiv 1\pmod{1-\omega}$, then $a^3\equiv 1\pmod 9$, or a penultimate result $a^3\equiv 1\pmod {(1-\omega)^4}$.

As a feeble effort, WLOG I tried to see how things might work, I looked at values in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ such that $a^3 = b^3 +c^3$ and $a=1-\omega$, or $a^3= -3\omega(1-\omega)$ and hoped to find the appropriate $b$ and $c$.

Thanks

Comment: What's $\omega$? A thrid root of unity?

Comment: Why is the hypothesis that none of $a, b, c$ is zero necessary? (I guess if this is what the book says, my objection is to the book, not to the OP.)

Comment: You refer to a prior congruence results. I think all you need to do is to check all possibilities for $x^3+y^3$ modulo $1-\omega$.

Comment: Start with the fact that $1-\omega$ divides $3$ and $a^3+b^3+c^3=s_1^3-3s_1s_2+3s_3$ where $s_1=a+b+c, s_2=ab+ac+bc, s_3=abc$. so $1-\omega$ divides $(a+b+c)^3$. Use unique factorization to show that thus $1-\omega$ divides $a+b+c$. Not sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks. I was wondering if I could do that, since in $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ $1,2,3$ are their own cubes. But the hint in the text of the question suggests to use the second problem result I mentioned above. With regards,

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Your finding leads to $a\equiv b\equiv c\pmod{1-\omega}$. In case $\equiv 0$, we are done. In case $\equiv 2$, just mutiply everything with $2$ to arrive in the remaining case $a\equiv b\equiv c\equiv 1\pmod{1-\omega}$. Then $a^3+b^3+c^3\equiv 3\pmod 9$ by the useful result.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Sorry to trouble you. I was thinking about your comment. You could have $1+1+1\equiv 0\pmod {1-\omega}$, but $1-\omega \nmid a,b,c$

Comment: But as Hagen von Eitzen remars, then the sum of the cubes is congruent to $3$ modulo $9$, and in particular is not $0$.

Comment: @Andrew: you have actually $3=(1-\omega)(2+\omega)$ which is stronger than your congruence so maybe useful for you. It seems to me you are near of an answer,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, that was the motivation of your previous question, FLT for the prime exponent $p$, in the so called « first case » where $p$ does not divide $abc$ in the Fermat equation. In chapter 1 of Washington’s « Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields », there is a complete proof for any $p$ such that $p$ does not divide the class number of $Q(\omega)$, where $\omega$ is a primitive $p$-th root of 1 (which is a weaker assumption than the principality of $Z[\omega])$. At the beginning of the proof of his thm. 1.1, Washington deals separately with the case $p$ = 3 when 3 does not divide $abc$, and this is straightforward by considering cubes of integers mod 9. So the point of your exercise is to show that $\lambda := 1 - \omega$ must divide $abc$ in the cubic Fermat equation (where we may of course take $a, b, c$ to be pairwise co-prime).

Here is an answer mimicking Wash.’s argument op. cit. and using your « penultimate result ». Write the Fermat equation as $a^3 + b^3 = c^3$. If $\lambda$ does not divide $a$, the residue class of a mod $\lambda$ is $\pm1$ (because 3 is totally ramified, see my previous answer), so $a^3\equiv \pm1 $ mod 9 in $Z$. Same thing for $b$ and $c$, hence $a^3 + b^3\equiv -2, 0, 2$ mod 9, whereas $c^3\equiv \pm 1 $ mod 9 : contradiction.

Comment: Dear Professor - Thank you for your kind answers. As you probably have guessed, I am a fervent but uneducated self-studier. I started in my late 60's and wish I was more proficient. If it is not too much of an imposition, maybe you would please add a remark with an intuitive explanation that goes beyond the "brute force" approach of cubing both sides of $a=1+b \lambda$ to get $a^3\equiv \pm 1\pmod 9$ in my previous question but does not entail ramification. With regards,

Comment: Well, your 2 requirements – « beyond brute force » and « not entailing ramification » seem rather contradictory. To derive information on a^3 from the hypothesis, what to do if not cubing ?  Once the calculations are done, it’s natural to check the divisibility by lambda of the factor b^3 – omega^2.b which pops out (as the hint suggests) .

Comment: Well, your 2 requirements – « beyond brute force » and « not entailing ramification » seem rather contradictory. To derive information on a^3 from the hypothesis, what to do if not cubing ?  Once the calculations are done, it’s natural to check the divisibility by lambda of the factor b^3 – omega^2.b which pops out (as the hint suggests) . It’s also logical to write it as a product b(b – omega)(b + omega) and check : - either lambda divides b, and we are done  - or lambda divides one of the 2 other factors, i.e. lambda divides b + 1 or b – 1...

Comment: ... There is no reason for b to satisfy this property if ramification is not involved. Write A = Z[omega] for short. Here we have seen that 3 is totally ramified, i.e. A/(lambda) = Z/(3) and b has not many choices. But in the 2 other possible cases (3 is inert or 3 is split), A/(lambda) is more complicated (see any course on quadratic fields). We could try and caculate using 3 = - omega^2.lambda^2, but this would be brute force ! After all, to work in a quadratic field allows you to enlarge your scope, but in return you must use the tools which were forged to deal with rings larger than Z .

Comment: Thank you for your most generous replies